# Make Jbutton fully mimic "X" button

Tags: java

I am developing an application that uses full screen and a JButton in the top right that should act as a Close "X" button for the application. Thing is, I would like to make it mimic completely the actual "X" button.

I'll explain, my program has already implemented ways to make the closing of the application do different things via settings menu (close/minimize/hide to tray) but those use the setDefaultCloseOperation and do not work with the JButton I set up, mainly because neither

```
System.exit(0);
```

or

```
Frame.dispose();
```

take into consideration setDefaultCloseOperation, so they will close the frame no matter what setDefaultCloseOperation  tells it to do.

Is there a way to create a button that follows the rules of setDefaultCloseOperation  or I have to change all the code to work around that?

Comment: Sounds like you've installed a WindowListener that responds to the Closing event.  You should simply direct your x button to that listener.

Comment: It seem that `JFrame` uses the `WindowClosing` event to determine how to handle the configured default close operation

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a **JButton** with an event, and into this event, just call the **System.exit(0);** function.

This is an example:

```
JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Do what you want before exit program
        System.exit(0);     // To exit your program
    //  frame.dispose();    // To "hide" the JFrame
    }
});
```